# Generating PDF report in Java using NetBeans

Tags: java

I am creating a software using Java in NetBeans, I almost finished. I am using Itext to save the report in pdf format and I am using SQLite as my database manager.

What I want is that to be able and select rows that have same records and save them as pdf in one place for each alike row. I know how I can generate the pdf report but don't know how to get rows with same records and save them as pdf.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for creating a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Comment: When creating your SQL query statement utilize the WHERE clause and perhaps the LIKE clause to retrieve same records into a ResultSet. You can then place your ResultSet into a 2D Array and create your PDF report utilizing the data within the array at your convenience.